# Why can't I edit my alerts email address in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services and am trying to edit the email address that my alerts and notifications get sent to.

I have found an article online that shows how to do it, however I do not get the "edit" button. The article can be found [here](http://visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications).

This is what I see:
[image: This is what I see]

This is what I expect to see:
[image: This is what I expect to see]

Have they removed this option? Or do I need to go somewhere else to change this setting?

Comment: What browser are you using? btw. You are mentioning TFS and Visual Studio Online (which is now Visual Studio Team Services), but which one are you using?

Comment: Sorry - Visual Studio Team Services, ill update the question

Comment: Alerts are sent to your Profile's email address to prevent VSTS from turning into a spam robot.

Comment: Do you have administration rights?

Comment: @jessehouwing - I had a look at my profile and I found a "Contact e-mail" field I can edit. Is it possible to use a separate email for different projects? It seems to all be controlled by that single email.

Comment: @TheShooter yes I have admin rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your preferred email. You can set it in your profile. You e-mail will set to this address by default.

However, for detail email alter, you still can edit the address to **send to the following email addresses**. Detail settings just as below picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I have found the page you mentioned and can see that I can edit my email for the different alert types. Right now I'm trying to edit the email that gets the alerts when someone mentions me in a comment under the discussions section of work item but I can't seem to find on the alerts admin page.

Comment: Did you mean the @ during the discussion of the work item such as https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/work/backlogs/add-work-items#add-to-the-discussion. I think this should be your default email. Which in your profile and the  "Contact e-mail" field

Comment: Yes that's the one. I found the "Contat e-mail" you mentioned. Is there no way to use a separate email for different "service accounts". E.g. Project1.visualstudio.com vs Project2.visualstudio.com

Comment: This can't be achieved for now.

Comment: That's a shame. Well i guess I have my answer, thank you for your help